# how can you track memory allocation in c++

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

The question I have is **how can you detect memory leaks in your c++ code.** 
What I have so far is overloaded the new and delete operators and to track the amount of memory being allocated/freed but this only tells me if there is a problem.  **How can you get more useful information for pinpointing the problem???**

Comment: Using specialized tools like valgrind or AQTime

Comment: You can find out where the allocation happened by using the `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` macros. You typically do something like `#define NEW ::new(__FILE, __LINE)` and then implement `void* operator new(std::size_t, char const*, int)`.

Comment: If you're working with Visual Studio: http://vld.codeplex.com/

Comment: Using the STL should reduce (remove?) memory leaks. otherwhise External tools are the best solution

Comment: the solution needs to be cross platform so anything implementation specific will not do the job

Answer (score 3):

On Linux look for [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), on Windows -  look for [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/). For a cross platform solution you might take a look on [this implementation](http://wyw.dcweb.cn/leakage.htm) with [doxygen here](http://nvwa.sourceforge.net/doc/current/debug__new_8cpp.html).

Comment: I need something that would be cross platform so anything like 3rd party tools or libraries are really out of the question

Answer (score 1):

You can use tools to do that: Valgrind, Purify, ... Depending on your environment some will work and some will not.